# Exporting to Collada --> Loss of Transparency

Tags: export, collada

I created an object with glass-like appearance upon rendering using raytracing in blender, but when I export to collada, the material's transparency doesn't seem to be transferred. Is there any way I can preserve the transparency of the material when I export?

My material properties are as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If i am not wrong.. transparency is not imported into any software(May be bug in libraries).
Transparency is exported as expected but cannot be imported back. 
You could verify by opening the exported file in web browser, and search for

> transparency

and see the value exported. you could also check by changing alpha value and re exporting..

Let me know if i am wrong..